# Give NeumannValue a nonlinear function

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I have the following simpler example of my actual problem which reproduces my question

```
domain = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}], Disk[{5, 5}, 0.5]];
a = 0.5; b = 0.2; g = 5;
sol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x, y], t] - g Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 
    NeumannValue[-((a u[t, x, y])/(
      b + u[t, x, y])) , (x - 5)^2 + (y - 5)^2 == 0.5^2], 
   u[0, x, y] == 1}, u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, y} \[Element] domain]
```

Which gives the error

[image: Error message]

Is it possible to give NeumannValue a nonlinear function?

Comment: Try predicate: `Norm[{x, y} - {5, 5}] >= .5` in the second argument of your `NeumannValue` - it works for me then, but I'm not sure why yours didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @flinty - I tried changing that and it still did not work. I get the same error. I think it is because $a u/(b+u)$ is nonlinear, but I do not know why Mathematica would have such a constraint for a Neumann boundary condition.

For what it's worth I am running Mathematica 11.1.

Comment: Your code work fine in  12.1.1

Answer (score 2):

The nonlinear Finite Element solver was added in version 12.0 and you'd need that to solve this PDE.

```
domain = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}], 
   Disk[{5, 5}, 0.5]];
a = 0.5; b = 0.2; g = 5;
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y], t] - 
      g Laplacian[u[t, x, y], {x, y}] == 
     NeumannValue[-((a u[t, x, y])/(b + u[t, x, y])), (x - 
           5)^2 + (y - 5)^2 == 0.5^2], u[0, x, y] == 1}, 
   u, {t, 0, 2}, {x, y} \[Element] domain];
Plot3D[sol[2, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] domain]
```

[image]